# How can I automatically add location from GPS log on my smartphone to SLR taken images?

Tags: metadata, smartphone, gps, automation

What software is best for adding gps data to photos from gps log i run on my android device?

I want to do as little manual labor as possible preferrably software does it all for me.

Look at photo timestamp
Find entry in GPS log and copy gps location to image EXIF

Desired feature, if GPS log interval is set every five minutes and photo timestamp is somewhere in between this two gps timestamps, program should calculate the path between point A and point B and enter stamp photo with approximate GPS location between this points.

Comment: I have the feeling this question has been asked a few times before, but I'm on mobile and can't search easily. Did you find anything yourself? If so, what issues did you run into? Were the answers outdated? Feel free to [edit] that into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What options do I have for GPS/Geotagging  with a digital SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-options-do-i-have-for-gps-geotagging-with-a-digital-slr)

Comment: Related: [Is there an EASY way to get geotagging with a compact camera without GPS?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88973/15871) It doesn't matter if the photos were captured with an SLR or a compact camera when you're adding GPS info to the EXIF info in post.

Answer (score 2):

I use GPSlogger. It starts and runs with the phone and will upload a GPS logfile to dropbox, google drive or a meriad of other options.
You can find it via Fdroid, it is not in the playstore.

I have it set to renew the log monthly and upload every 3 hours.
When I get home I upload my pics to the computer and then match them to their location using the file which usually has arrived by then.

Comment: GPSlogger never worked correctly while the phone was "just carried" (see https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger/issues/916). I use Ape@map (Unsure it's available in non-German) to log the track, then I convert it to a simple format. I think exiftool can use the shooting date to add corresponding positions automatically, but I never tried that; instead I do it manually (in Lightroom).

Comment: I use my own [Python Script to match file (txt csv) from GPSLogger to my photos using exiftool](https://github.com/jcubic/gps.py), the script is simple and only matches the timestamps. I only have one issue with --shift, I'm still not sure if it's timezone or daylight saving time. Also found recently that my camera doesn't have automatic daylight saving mode. To check if the GPS is added properly I use [Pic2Map](https://www.pic2map.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom will take a bunch of photos and a .gpx file and tag all the photos with location.  You select all the photos, then go to the map tab, load the tracklog and autotag the photos

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geotag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net/) software. You import the photos (from local storage), load logger file (it support GPX files) then you rightclick and set the location for one or all files. If you want you can lookup for city, country. I will recommend you to store information in XMP files and do not touch the RAW files.

For full compatibility check the project web site. And when you start with big logger files set maximum heap (this is java program) to at least 1024MB:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar geotag-0.103.jar
```

BTW it is odd for me to set interval to 5 minutes, on my phone I use two different GPS loggers and for entire day any of them consume less than 10% of the batter with interval of 3 seconds.

Do not forget to sync the camera time to be as much as possible to GPS time and set proper timezone.

Answer (score 0):

(This was going to be a comment)

The least amount of work is using a camera with GPS. These are widely available on the market (both used and new) and eliminate building a brittle kludge.

Comment: I find fewer of them on the market these days and one might want to buy a camera based on other features.

Answer (score 0):

For a python command line tool, I used [gpx2exif](https://github.com/gvellut/gpx2exif) successfully.

```
pip install gpx2exif

gpx2exif image geopaparazzi_20200315_183754.gpx dsc004239.jpg --delta 2m25s
```